# sf::st_buffer singleSide not working (as expected)

Tags: r, sf

problem: I want a buffer on only one side of a linestring (I believe this van done by setting the singleSide-argument of `sf::st_buffer()` to TRUE. But is does nog seem to be working on my data

**reproducible code**

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
testdata <- structure(list(WVK_ID = 166309055, geometry = structure(list(
  structure(c(4.34037292418725, 4.34083040467967, 4.34106372343137, 
              4.3413434255223, 4.34158028405102, 4.34189035998138, 4.34237136173266, 
              4.34261324610867, 4.34319032705945, 4.34392382792536, 4.34416950423526, 
              4.3445337644722, 4.34502883558736, 4.34527718851826, 4.34577663323092, 
              4.34652937419189, 4.35195260425213, 4.35245688266433, 4.35271054206837, 
              4.35308272954346, 4.35359637099288, 4.35385433508889, 4.35411284074363, 
              4.35489454493271, 4.35533189473573, 4.35558964937434, 4.35610195288945, 
              4.35671497696178, 4.35810271046744, 4.3601122108754, 4.36045804234936, 
              52.0739221011134, 52.0737022475421, 52.073594352647, 52.0734683235652, 
              52.0733638999539, 52.0732305203296, 52.0730273377176, 52.0729268649073, 
              52.0726896627538, 52.0723958776278, 52.0722989471161, 52.0721569104742, 
              52.0719666397399, 52.0718723211595, 52.0716865129238, 52.0714114964924, 
              52.06944852256, 52.069267762408, 52.0691789705958, 52.069051992985, 
              52.0688815429093, 52.0687976484049, 52.0687143872975, 52.0684718044186, 
              52.0683320973632, 52.0682476435526, 52.068075694087, 52.0678630912521, 
              52.0673600821074, 52.0666265613765, 52.0664822838409), 
            dim = c(31L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), 
  class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, 
  bbox = structure(c(xmin = 4.34037292418725, ymin = 52.0664822838409, xmax = 4.36045804234936, ymax = 52.0739221011134), class = "bbox"), 
  crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), 
  n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(WVK_ID = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = st_buffer(testdata, dist = 100, singleSide = TRUE)) +
  geom_sf(data = testdata)
```

leads to the following output:

[image]

I would expect a buffer on 1 side of the linestring only. As can be achieved using the code
`plot(st_buffer(st_linestring(rbind(c(0,0), c(10,0))), 2, singleSide = TRUE), axes = TRUE)`
Why is this not working for my LINESTRING?

**sessioninfo**

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.2   stringr_1.4.1   dplyr_1.0.10    purrr_0.3.5     readr_2.1.3     tidyr_1.2.1     tibble_3.1.8   
 [8] ggplot2_3.4.0   tidyverse_1.3.2 sf_1.0-9       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0    haven_2.5.1         gargle_1.2.1        colorspace_2.0-3    vctrs_0.5.0         generics_0.1.3     
 [7] utf8_1.2.2          rlang_1.0.6         e1071_1.7-12        pillar_1.8.1        glue_1.6.2          withr_2.5.0        
[13] DBI_1.1.3           dbplyr_2.2.1        modelr_0.1.10       readxl_1.4.1        lifecycle_1.0.3     munsell_0.5.0      
[19] gtable_0.3.1        cellranger_1.1.0    rvest_1.0.3         tzdb_0.3.0          class_7.3-20        fansi_1.0.3        
[25] broom_1.0.1         Rcpp_1.0.9          KernSmooth_2.23-20  scales_1.2.1        backports_1.4.1     classInt_0.4-8     
[31] googlesheets4_1.0.1 jsonlite_1.8.3      fs_1.5.2            hms_1.1.2           stringi_1.7.8       grid_4.2.2         
[37] cli_3.4.0           tools_4.2.2         magrittr_2.0.3      proxy_0.4-27        crayon_1.5.2        pkgconfig_2.0.3    
[43] ellipsis_0.3.2      xml2_1.3.3          reprex_2.0.2        googledrive_2.0.0   lubridate_1.9.0     timechange_0.1.1   
[49] assertthat_0.2.1    httr_1.4.4          rstudioapi_0.14     R6_2.5.1            units_0.8-0         compiler_4.2.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `singleSide` argument is ignored when the `s2` library is used to do the buffering. To use GEOS instead, you can run `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` before calling `st_buffer`. Note that GEOS will interpret `dist` to be in degrees rather than meters.

Comment: Thank you fo this! I submitted an enhancement-issue on the sf github page to include this information in the helpfile of the st_buffer-function.